# How to create a path for CL NUI to Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: c++

I have installed CL NUI and I have run the program. It works perfectly. But now I would like to use CL NUI in one of my projects. I am using Visual Studio 2010, but I am unsure on how to create a path so that the project can detect CL NUI library. I tried finding examples but mostly it is about openni and opencv. If anyone can guide me, I would be very grateful.

Answer (score 0):

From the [CL NUI Platform page](http://codelaboratories.com/kb/nui):

You can find this example project in “C:\Program Files\Code Laboratories\CL NUI Platform\SDK\Samples”

Requirements to Run:

- Microsoft .NET 3.5 SP1 Redistributable
- Requirements to Compile:

  - Visual Studio 2010 - Student Version or Professional
- [Or review the C API here…](http://codelaboratories.com/forums/viewthread/416/#code)

And the [last link gives an overview of the SDK](http://codelaboratories.com/forums/viewthread/416/#code)

Edit: Update to comments:

I've downloaded and installed the platform installer and it includes a C dll + h files + .lib files.

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Code Laboratories\CL NUI Platform\SDK\Bin
C:\Program Files (x86)\Code Laboratories\CL NUI Platform\SDK\Include
C:\Program Files (x86)\Code Laboratories\CL NUI Platform\SDK\Lib
C:\Program Files (x86)\Code Laboratories\CL NUI Platform\SDK\Samples
C:\Program Files (x86)\Code Laboratories\CL NUI Platform\SDK\Bin\CLNUIDevice.dll
C:\Program Files (x86)\Code Laboratories\CL NUI Platform\SDK\Include\CLNUIDevice.h
C:\Program Files (x86)\Code Laboratories\CL NUI Platform\SDK\Lib\CLNUIDevice.lib
```

I would just use Visual Studio to Create an unmanaged C++ project and then include these items.

There are lots of samples of projects on the [code.microsoft.com](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/vstudio/)

Comment: The example project is in c#, I am using c++, and I dont understand. Do I have to create a new header and add the C API in there? and what about the CL NUI lib?

Comment: Do you mean to copy paste the dll and files into my visual studio project or create a path in the project property pages?

Comment: now I receive an error that says fatal error LNK1120: 6 unresolved externals. 


'IP.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_GetNUICameraDepthFrameRGB32 referenced in function main'
'IP.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_GetNUICameraColorFrameRGB32 referenced in function main'

and other _imp_Get

Any suggestions?

Comment: Use Dumpbin to dump the library and see if there are in the lib/dll and if they are then you need to ensure you link correctly. If not then you need contact CL to determine where they are.